# Command Line Arguments with Sinatra

Tags: ruby, sinatra, command-line-arguments

I have a `Sinatra` program that I am creating, and I would like to be able to pass in command line arguments to this app when I launch it. The problem that I have is that I'm not sure how to do this. I've tried `Trollop` and looked at `OptParser`. `Trollop` doesn't appear to work with `Sinatra` because `OptParser` seems to be "default" parser with `Sinatra`. Is this true? If so, how can I customize the types of arguments accepted when I launch my app?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
ruby app.rb hello
# app.rb
 require 'sinatra'

get '/' do
  ARGV[0]
end
```

Now when I visit `localhost:4567` (where Thin hosts my sinatra app), I see a page that says hello.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you can use environment variables.

Example borrowed from here: https://gist.github.com/benlovell/351962

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'sinatra'

get '/' do
  ENV['envvar']
end
```

Then run:

```
envvar=something ruby app.rb
```